# react-leaflet and leaflet-editable: create additional marker during event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to implement functionality which will allow me to, when placing a marker with leaflet-editable, hold control while clicking to place a marker before immediately initializing another marker to be placed. The result would be that the user could hold control to rapidly place several markers in a row.

I have attempted to implement this functionality by responding to the `editable:drawing:commit` event and calling `map.editTools.createMarker` there. However, it appears that doing this has no effect; after placing the marker, the user leaves the editing mode and has to manually initiate placing another marker.

I also attempted responding to `editable:drawing:end`, however this seems to have inconsistent behavior, where sometimes it will act as described and sometimes it won't place a second marker.

[Here is the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-n48p8?file=/src/index.js) I was able to reproduce a minimal example in. Is there a bug with how events are handled or am I simply capturing the wrong event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time playing with this, and the problem is the asynchronous nature of useState calls in react.  When you do this:

```js
"editable:drawing:commit": (event) => {
  if (event.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
    setAdditionalMarker(true);
  }
},
```

This state change is not immediate.  It seems the `drawing:end` event happens immediately after the `drawing:commit` event when placing a singular marker.  So when you listen for the `end` event:

```js
"editable:drawing:end": (event) => {
  if (additionalMarker) {
    addMarker();
    setAdditionalMarker(false);
  }
}
```

`additionalMarker` is not yet true, because `setAdditionalMarker(true)` has not yet registered with react, as it is async.  So that `if` statement is never called.

From a UX perspective, it also sort of doesn't make sense, because even if useState was synchronous, if the user is holding down ctrl when they make a click, but then they release the ctrl key before clicking the map again, it would stay in edit mode.  But on keyup, it should exit edit mode.  My take was to attach `keyup` and `keydown` listeners to the *document*.  On keydown we can `setAdditionalMarker(true)`, and the opposite on keyup.  If `additionalMarkers` is true, we refire `addMarkers()` after a click event. However, if a keyup event happens, we can call `map.editTools.commitDrawing()` to force an exit of edit mode, and the page cursor goes back to normal.

We *still* have the async useState problem though, because on keyup, we set `additionalMarkers` to false, and fire the `editable:drawing:end` event at the same time, but `setAdditionalMarkers` is async, so `additionalMarkers` is still true, and we get stuck in editable mode.  To fix this, I wrapped `map.editTools.commitDrawing()` in a 50ms timeout, so that it happens *after* the async useState call completes.  Its a bit hacky, but it works and is good for UX. There's probably a more proper way to do that.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-ctrl-click-7cs0u)

**Note: I'm on a mac so I changed the key to lsiten for to the left command key...you may have to adjust the keycode in the keydown and keyup events for windows or for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect answer! From a UX perspective, I was only considering knowing whether CTRL was being pressed while the click was happening, which in retrospect would not have been intuitive. The async issue also makes sense, because it explains why, in my CodeSandbox, a second marker would only be placed every other time or so.

Comment: I was thinking about this....I hate the `setTimeout`, its mega-hacky.  If you converted this to a class component, you can take advantage of the `this.setState({ additionalMarkers: false }, callback)` pattern, and manage the asychronicity in that callback.  Food for thought.

Comment: Would adding a `useEffect` hook work to check when the `additionalMarkers` becomes false?

Comment: Yes you could organize it with a useEffect, you could wrap `map.editTools.commitDrawing()` in a useEffect.  [Here is a CSB that does that](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-ctrl-click-with-useffect-xwgrv)